# access sql and the LIKE keyword

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I am working on an addin for Visio using Access as a backend database. In one of my forms I am filling a datagridview with parts from a table. In this DGV I wish to include only parts of type "connector" and also filter out connector parts which have the word "banana" (banana connectors) in the description. The line of sql I came up with seemed simple enough, when I execute it in a query window within Access it works as expected. However, when I execute the exact statement within the context of my addin, it still returns the banana connectors! Can anyone tell me what the difference is?
Below is the code from my addin.
Thanks for any tips

```
Using con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & VE_docPath & VE_currentProject & ".accdb;Persist Security Info=True")
            Using cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("", con)
                Try
                    sql = "SELECT PartDefID, PartNumber, PartNumberAlt, PartDescription, ShellType, ElementCount, TerminalCount, KitNumber FROM PartDefinitions WHERE PartClass = 1 AND (PartDescription NOT LIKE '*banana*')"
                    cmd.CommandText = sql
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    cmd.Connection = con
                    con.Open()
                    Dim daGet As New OleDbDataAdapter()
                    daGet.SelectCommand = cmd
                    daGet.Fill(TableConnector)
                    Me.PartDefDataGridView.DataSource = TableConnector
                    If Me.PartDefDataGridView.RowCount > 0 Then
                        Me.PartDefDataGridView.Columns("PartDefID").Visible = False 'hide this column in the DGV
                        Me.PartDefDataGridView.ClearSelection()
                        Me.PartDefDataGridView.Rows(0).Selected = True
                    End If
                Catch SqlError As System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlTypeException
                    MsgBox(SqlError.Message, MsgBoxStyle.SystemModal, "Error")
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.SystemModal, "Error")
                End Try
            End Using
        End Using
```

Comment: There does not seem to be anything there that helps. I have no errors per se with my sql or vb code. If I run this statement "SELECT PartDefID, PartNumber, PartNumberAlt, PartDescription, ShellType, ElementCount, TerminalCount, KitNumber FROM PartDefinitions WHERE PartClass = 1 AND PartDescription NOT LIKE '*banana*'" inside an access query window it does as expected. When I run it from my vb code it still returns the "bananas"

Comment: Answer in referenced question indicates use % instead of * for wildcard character.

Comment: yes I know % does not work in access sql but * does

Comment: I know and thought the answer odd but it was accepted. % can work in Access if db is set for ANSI-92 but the answer did not indicate that was necessary.

Comment: What happens if you revise your OleDbCommand statement to use `PartDescription NOT LIKE '%banana%'`

Comment: Holy Platypus Batman, that worked! I assumed it would not because it did not work in a query window inside access (where I often test my sql). Just goes to show, one should not assume. There is obviously something going on though between what the compiler is generating and what access accepts as valid

Comment: Thanks HansUp! how do I mark this as solved?